Suppose that $f$ satisfies $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 f(x) = 1$. Prove that $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$ is convergent.
Suppose that $f : [1,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function satisfying $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 f(x) = 1$. Prove that $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$ is convergent.
I have tried using the comparison theorem, but I cannot think of a comparison for $f(x)$ that I can integrate. I tried using derivative($x^2 f(x) $), but I do not think that this is allowed since we do not know that $f$ is differentiable. Any help using methods learned up until calculus 2 would be much appreciated.

Did you try to use limit comparison? Here you have a very big hint with what function you should compare.

As $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2f(x)=1$, there exists some $x_0$ such that $x^2f(x)\leq 2$, or equivalently, $f(x)\leq\dfrac{2}{x^2}$  for $x\geq x_0$.
As $$\displaystyle\int_{x_0}^{\infty} \dfrac{2}{x^2}dx=\dfrac{2}{x_0}<\infty,$$
by the direct comparison test $\displaystyle\int_{x_0}^{\infty} f(x)\space dx$ converges.
Using that $f$ is continuous we find $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{x_0} f(x)\space dx$ is finite and so $$\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)\space dx=\displaystyle\int_{1}^{x_0} f(x)\space dx+\displaystyle\int_{x_0}^{\infty} f(x)\space dx<+\infty$$
